# which is better in this case? re-usability or redundancy

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic

I have a page where user will see product details based on the product id.  And same page can be seen by admin also. I have a template to render html.

Admin will have more control on that page like, He can edit, delete, and many more.
User can just see it and purchase.

**Case 1: Use same template by adding conditions, to show content based on user**
Pros
1) Its easy when we require to modify template or theme anything.
2) Re-usability

Cons
1) Its becomes complex when there are many conditions and takes lots of time to debug any issue.
2) Any bug in that template would affect both admin page and user page.

**Case 2: Using different templates**
Pros
1) Its easy when there are many complex conditions.
2) And it makes the code independent. Bug in admin template wouldn't effect user template

Cons
1) Its an issue when we have to modify the template or theme. (extra dependency)

Which is the better option? what is the right tactic to go?

should be adaptive based on the complexity? I would like to see your opinion on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a shared base that contains the overlap between user and admin. Then, use decorator pattern to add admin functionality.

By decorating the base you avoid bugs in the admin portion to affect the users. So you retain re-usability while adding functionality.

Comment: Yes this is the one option I liked the most. Symfony2 php framework is also using same design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

why not make use of Factory or Abstact Factory pattern for such kind of issue...becase this two patterns deal with the family of objects..and reduce complexivity as well as make your code easy to maintain...

Example : [Abstract Factory](http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html)

Comment: I am looking in to it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should have your design like this:
1. Suppose your product page has 2 buttons
2. Purchase button - For common user
3. Ship item button - For admin
4. Now showing this button should not be dependent on whether user is admin or not, but on whether u want to show that component that page

you should have `PageModel` class which has 2 boolean attributes

```
boolean showPurchaseButton
boolean showShipButton
```

you should have only one template/page creation code.
In template class,
 u should add components to page like this:

```
if(showPurchaseButton){
//add purchase button to template
}
if(showShipButton){
//add ship button to template
}
```

while creating page, you can populate PageModel depending on user like this:

```
//common user
PageModel model = new PageModel()
model.setshowPurchaseButton(true);
model.setshowShipButton(false);

//for admin user
PageModel model = new PageModel()
model.setshowPurchaseButton(false);
model.setshowShipButton(true);

//while creating your template pass this model to it.
```

This way u'll have flexibilty to add as many components to ur template.
and also debugging will become easy because , when populating values in page model, u'll get idea that what components u r showing for which user. this section of code will act as ur control panel.